# CAXLXS spreadsheet cells without colors when open with excell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spreadsheet, axlsx, caxlsx

I´m generate an spreadsheet with colors into cells, and when I a open the file with Open office or google spreadsheet works fine, but when with Excel the colors desappear. Code:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.xlsx do
    render layout: false,
           handlers: [:caxlsx],
           formats: [:xlsx],
           template: 'file.xlsx.axlsx'
  end
```

Gem:

```
gem 'caxlsx', '3.0.1'
gem 'caxlsx_rails', '0.6.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I find out the solution. Basically, Excell handles with hexadecimal colors differently, and since I'm was using hexadecimal with the format `#FF000000` that is compatible with google spreadsheets and open office, but incompatible with excell, excell generates wrong color cells. the solution is to use hexa codes without # and six digits, like `FF0000`